# Notifications are not displayed in Android Auto

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-auto, android-automotive

I've had trouble trying to show notifications in Android Auto.

I have followed the configuration guide for adding support for Android Auto[1](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/auto) and the one for notifications in Android Auto [2](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/notifications). But the documentation for the Notification is not clear to me. So I am asking for help if something is wrong with my code.

Currently, the notification is showing on the device, but not on Android auto. I'm testing using the Desktop Head Unit[3](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing)

Thanks!

```
  fun builder(subject : String, title: String, context: Context) : String {

    val ACTION_REPLY = "com.example.native_notification.Notifications.reply"
    val ACTION_MARK_AS_READ = "com.example.native_notification.Notifications.mark_as_read"

    try {
        //Create the NotificationChannel
        val channelId = "NOTIFICATION_AUTO";
        val name = "Notificaciones android auto";
        val descriptionText = "Notify about status of your services";
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val mChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance)
        mChannel.description = descriptionText;
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)

        val intent = Intent().apply {
            putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "intent working")
        }

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 2 ,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)


        val icon: Icon = Icon.createWithResource(context, R.drawable.ic_logo)

        val longMessage: Long = 1

        var action: Notification.Action =
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                Notification.Action.Builder(icon,
                    "Ok,", pendingIntent)
                    .setSemanticAction(Notification.Action.SEMANTIC_ACTION_MARK_AS_READ)
                    .build()
            } else {
                TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < P")
            }


        val p = Person.Builder().setName("Gopass").build()

        val style: Notification.Style = Notification.MessagingStyle(p)
            .setConversationTitle("this is a title")
            .addMessage(Notification.MessagingStyle
                .Message("this is the text", longMessage, p))

        val newMessageNotification = Notification.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(subject)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setStyle(style)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .addAction(action)
            .extend(Notification.CarExtender())
            .build()
            
        return notificationManager.notify(0, newMessageNotification).toString();

    }
    catch(ex: Exception) {
        return ex.toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To show notification in the car you need to add

```
CarAppExtender.Builder()
                    .setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                    .build()
```